# Assembly 8086 - Can't push two symbols

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

This program converts binary to decimal and I'm supposed to push "$$" into a stack, so that later it would recognize "$$" and end the program. However, it gives me an error that "$$" is an invalid parameter for PUSH.

Everything else works for this program, I just need to somehow mark the end in the stack without an error. I have tried putting in numbers such as "00" and it creates an infinite loop instead of an error. I'm using emu8086, if that's the case.

```
PUSH    ax
PUSH    cx
PUSH    dx

MOV cx, 10  
PUSH    "$$"    ; pushes $$ to mark the end
Divide:
MOV dx, 0       
DIV cx      
PUSH    dx      
CMP ax, 0   
JA  Divide


MOV ah, 2
Print:
POP dx      
CMP dx, "$$"  ; compares if there's a mark, to end the program
JE  End
ADD dl, '0'     
INT 21h     
JMP Print
```

Comment: What assembler do you use and what are translation flags? `push imm16` available for 80186 but absent in 8086.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An instruction like `PUSH "$$"` would normally not be legal for an emulator that is based on the 8086 architecture where it was not possible to push an immediate value like "$$".

The workaround is to mov the value to a register and push the register:

```
mov     dx, "$$"
push    dx
```

---

In your program specifically, you can push the CONST 10 (already present in CX), because no remainder will ever equal that value:

```
MOV  cx, 10  
PUSH CX    ; pushes 10 to mark the end
Divide:
MOV  dx, 0       
DIV  cx      
PUSH dx      
CMP  ax, 0   
JA   Divide


MOV  ah, 2
Print:
POP  dx      
CMP  dx, CX  ; compares if there's a mark, to end the program
JE   End
ADD  dl, '0'     
INT  21h     
JMP  Print
```

Comment: Is this $$ as in 0x2424 or $$ as in section start? I'm guessing the former.

Comment: @puppydrum64 Why would you guess? The OP already wrote for what purpose they want to use the value '$$' == 0x2424. It's a sentinel they put on the stack so that their second loop can detect when it's time to stop iterating.

Comment: I didn't see that but I suppose the quotation marks around `"$$"` implies that it's ASCII